# Is there a way to have multiple arguments in a command with discord py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I’m creating a discord bot using discord py and would like to have a kick command that dms the user a reason upon being kicked.

-kick @user reason

When I kick the user with a reason attached it doesn’t kick the user and I get an error in console saying can not find the user

Here is the code

```
@client.command(aliases=['Kick'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx,member : discord.Member,*,reason= 'no reason'):
    await ctx.send(f'{member.name} was kicked from the Server!\nand a Dm was sendet by me as a Information for him')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=2)
    await member.send(f'**You was kicked from {ctx.guild.name}\nthe Stuff Team dont tell me the reason?**')
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
    print(f"{ctx.author} ----> just used {prefix}kick")
```

And yes I have tried Google, the discord py API guide with no luck

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Please provide the traceback

Comment: 2 mins I’ll send it now

Comment: MemberNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member
"test" not found.

Comment: Test was my reason for the kick ^

Comment: What did you typed? `-kick @test test`?

Comment: I did -kick @testalt test (it’s a real account)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to the post of how the message looks like you sent?

Comment: It’s in the console id rather not send it I don’t want to accidentally leak my name

Answer (score 0):

You can give a nice error message. It raises [`MemberNotFound`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=membernotfound#discord.ext.commands.MemberNotFound).

Then you can make a [local error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=membernotfound#discord.ext.commands.MemberNotFound).

```py
@kick.error
async def kick_command_error(ctx, err):
    if isinstance(err, commands.MemberNotFound):
        await ctx.send('Hey! The member you gave is invalid or was not found. Please try again by `@`mentioning them or using the ID.')
```

Comment: The error is caused because of specifying two arguments

Comment: It's a `MemberNotFound`. It doesn't happen just because you let it take an extra argument. What input did you give to the command? Are they actually in the guild (kicking requires the `Member`, unlike bans)?

Comment: -kick @testalt test (yes it is a real account in the server)

Comment: Could be a caching issue (although I doubt that). Try it on some other account and see if it executes properly.

Comment: Already tried with my friends account same thing it gave the same error

Comment: Maybe your `members` intent isn't enabled? Are you sure that it worked perfectly before adding that extra argument?

Comment: Yes it had tested it with 2 different users twice before I added the extra argument

Comment: Yeah I've just tested this myself and it works fine. How are you getting the users? Is it the full mention format (where it pings them and turns a different color) or just `@username` or `@username#discriminator`?

Comment: Just got to mention them it kicks and then sends the user “you have been kicked from [server]”

Comment: The discord.py `Member` converter is pretty strict about this for some reason. It really only accepts a mention, `actual_username#xxxx`, or the ID itself. Glad you got it working though.

Comment: Yeah it’s weird I tried another method before and it just didn’t want to work for some weird reason but anyway it works now just gotta figure this reason thing out now which is another huge headache

Comment: You're always free to write your own converters and only fall back to the `discord.Member` one, although it can be annoying sometimes (I used it in a currency bot to let you type `max` and use shorthands `1k->1000`). It also doesn't work with nicknames, you have to type out the full username that is also case sensitive.

Comment: Yeah I might do that but one step at a time otherwise there is just loads to do at once